# Implement the FirebasePushNotificationPlugin combined with Local Notifcation in Xamarin forms

Tags: firebase, plugins, xamarin.forms, push-notification

I have implemented the FirebasePushNotificationPlugin(https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin). 
Now I have to show the Image within the notification, which I am able to show using Local Notification, but with this am not able to redirect to a particular page in Xamarin Forms. Which event I should require to do so? Also, how to use the Handler for FirebasePushNotificationPlugin?
Thank you.

I have tried to create the Local Notification along with FirebasePushNotificationPlugin, Please find the code that I have implemented below

//push notification - is the data I have received

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
var dataSerialize = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pushNotification);
intent.PutExtra("data", dataSerialize);
            // Create a PendingIntent; we're only using one         PendingIntent (ID = 0):
            const int pendingIntentId = 0;
            PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, pendingIntentId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

            // Instantiate the builder and set notification elements, including pending intent:
            Android.Support.V4.App.NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new Android.Support.V4.App.NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "FirebasePushNotificationChannel")
                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .SetContentTitle(pushNotification.title)
                .SetContentText(pushNotification.body)
                .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Sound | (int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate)
                .SetPriority((int)Android.App.NotificationPriority.High)
                .SetSmallIcon(resourceId);

            // Instantiate the Image (Big Picture) style:
            Android.Support.V4.App.NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle picStyle = new Android.Support.V4.App.NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();

            // Convert the image to a bitmap before passing it into the style:
            picStyle.BigPicture(Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, resourceId));

            // Set the summary text that will appear with the image:
            picStyle.SetSummaryText(pushNotification.body);

            // Plug this style into the builder:
            builder.SetStyle(picStyle);

            // Build the notification:
            Notification notification = builder.Build();

            // Get the notification manager:
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

            // Publish the notification:
            const int notificationId = 0;
            try
            {
                notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```

Comment: public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) is the event you have to override. Take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push

Comment: I have tried this, but when app is in background not able to show the image. I am only able to show when the app is in foreground.

Comment: Ah! Hmm, I haven't tried implementing Firebase from scratch, just implemented the MS App Center Push Notifications and it was pretty straight forward.